# How can I render animation frames transparent?

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to render a rotating logo frame by frame with a transparent background (80 frames). I've gone to Film > check transparent but it still shows up with a black background in every PNG.
[image]

I've also unchecked use alpha in compositing panel[image]

Comment: it seems to be transparent in your Render Layer no?

Comment: Make sure to RGBA, not just RGB, also, you can save the alpha and use it as a transparent mask

Comment: @moonboots yes it is transparent

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, just needed to check RGBA.